# D3.js map that automatically updates from google form’s answer sheet

Tags: d3.js, google-sheets, leaflet, google-forms

I am trying to make a visualization with D3.js that fetches data from a google sheet (generated through google forms) and automatically updates the visualization when new data is added (i.e. a user responds to the survey).

I am trying to set up the workflow and, since this is the first time I do something like this, I was hoping someone with more experience could help spot any flows and solve my issue.

**Objective:**

Create a map that automatically updates (i.e. create a new circle) when a user adds data.
Users add data through google form: this includes their name, location (three fields: street name - number - city), and a multiple choice answer.

As new data is added to the answer sheet, the address fields are converted into a “full address” column (which concatenates the three fields) and another column where the full address is converted into long/lat coordinates
A new pin is added to the map; its position is determined by the long/lat coordinates

**Proposed workflow:**

1. Create and style map with Leaflet and Mapbox respectively (as shown
   in [this tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html))
2. Create an additional layer that contains the data from the
   spreadsheets (the cirlces), as explained [here](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/)
3. Use the [Geocode by Awesome Table add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geocode-by-awesome-table/cnhboknahecjdnlkjnlodacdjelippfg?utm_source=permalink) to concatenate address fields and convert to long/lat coordinates
4. Load data from google sheet as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/tmaybe/6246014) (two options)

My first question is whether you think this is a viable workflow or if there are better tools to achieve my objective.

Assuming this is a good idea, I already have an issue. The Geocode concatenation and conversion need to be done manually. That means that when a new response is added to the answer sheet, the `full address` and `long/lat` columns are not filled in automatically.

Any idea how I could solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple of days working on it I managed to make it function the way I wanted. [Here is the bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/Federicopvs/dd6a365c4145c79c274bc52dc789ab30) if anyone is interested ;)

Comment: if the visualization does not work is because I removed my google map javascript API key from the head section.. If you insert a valid key the code should function normally